# The 'public / static' modifier is not valid for this item

Tags: c#

I created a script to add sounds in the game like jump and hit and I have an error that I can not solve it still says `The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item` and I say in unity im la just the way `The static modifier is not valid for this item` can help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoundManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AudioClip Hit_HurtSound, Jump2Sound;
    static AudioSource audioSrc;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Hit_HurtSound = Resources.Load<AudiotClip> ("Hit_Hurt");
        Jump2Sound = Resources.Load<AudiotClip> ("Jump2");

        audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
              public static void PlaySound (string clip)
        {
            switch (clip)
            {
                case "Jump2":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(Jump2Sound);
                    break;

                case "Hit_Hurt":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(Hit_HurtSound);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a method inside a method, did you really intend to do that?

Comment: this script I did after a tutorial on yt and I don't know why it gives me these errors

Comment: Then you likely didn't follow the tutorial closely enough, this code cannot compile in this version of C#.

Comment: Could you change the phrase "I say in unity im la just the way" to make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @DavidG said in his comment, you cannot have a method an a method. It should look like this:

```
public static void PlaySound (string clip)
{
    switch (clip)
    {
        case "Jump2":
            audioSrc.PlayOneShot(Jump2Sound);
            break;

        case "Hit_Hurt":
            audioSrc.PlayOneShot(Hit_HurtSound);
            break;
    }
}
```

You have to remove this lines (and its `}`)

```
void Update()
{
```

Comment: @Presi Asking for people to mark answers or vote is considered bad form here. Also, we should really be closing questions like this as typos as they aren't really useful to other people.